# SQL movie database diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, diagram

Im working on a small school project where im creating a movie database in SQL. I've created the tables and was wondering if I will encounter any problems with the model i created.

Thanks in advance.

Current diagram
[image]

Edit:

Here is the new diagram

[image]

Comment: You don't just have 1 actor per movie, right?

Comment: Movies can have more than one director.  Also, if you have `MoviesGenres`, you don't need `Movies.GenreId`.  Look at the similarities between `Actors` and `Directors` - you appear to have a `Person` table trying to get out.  Do you need to store role information (like who the actors portrayed)?

Comment: Why you have GenreId in the Movies Table, you already managed the Genres in bridge table as a movie can have multiple Genres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MovieDetails is bad design. You need one row in MovieDetails per actor, while the director will be the same, which is data duplication. Instead, the Movie table should have a foreign key referencing director, then a MovieActor table should represent the many to many relationship between movies and actors.

Technically, there's also no reason to have different tables for Directors and Actors since you have the same data in the tables. You could just as well have a Person table with both.

Comment: Ok so in the Movie table i have a DirectorID which references DirectorID in the Directors table and in MovieDetails(MovieActor) i have MovieID and ActorID.
Is that what you mean?

Comment: @grimsan55 Exactly. When making connections like this, you should always consider the relationship. Since movie-director is a 1 to many relationship, you put a reference where there can only be one: A movie can only have 1 director, so you put the reference there. If you want all the movies for a director, you simply check which movies reference him, and you'll get the "many" part of the relationship. When there's a many-to-many situation like movie-actor, you need a table representing the connection, in this case MovieDetails (MovieActor is a better name for this representation though).

Comment: Thank you!
as suggested by a few here i should also have a Genre table, should it reference to a new table, lets say a MovieGenre table? or should it reference to the movieactor table? In my head it seems like a new many-to-many relation is better? Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You are correct, you should only add data to the MovieActor table if it pertains to the actual connection (for example, MovieActor could have a salary field which shows the salary the actor earned for that movie). movie-genre is a many to many relationship (a genre can be applied to many movies, and a movie can have many genres) so yes, a MovieGenre table would make perfect sense.

Comment: It could be a lot of issues, possibly that the Directors table does not exist. Remember, if you're remaking the database, you need to create the directors table before you create the movie table since movies reference directors.

Answer (score 0):

How about (I am only showing the relevant columns)

```
movie table
-----------
id
title


person
------
id
name


cast table
----------
movie_id
person_id
movie_role_id (actor, director, ...)


role_type table
----------------
id
name   (actor, director, ...)


genres table
------------
id
name


movie_genres table
------------------
movie_id
genre_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the following structure:

```
movie(id, title, year, rating, plot, length)

actor(id, first name, last name, nationality, birth_date)
director(id, first name, last name, nationality, birth_date)

movie_x_actor(movie_id, actor_id)
movie_x_director(movie_id, director_id)
```

This is, of course, just the simplest example.
You can, for instance add a movie_series table like:

```
movie_series(id, title)

movie_x_movie_series(movie_id, series_id, plot_order_number)
```

and, like @Juergen described, a movie usually belongs to more than one genre so:

```
genres(id, genre_name, genre_description)
movie_x_genres(movie_id, genre_id)
```

You should definitely take a look at [one-to-many and many-to-many relationships between rows in tables](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/).

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Im only a few weeks in to the course and its a lot to handle :) But i appreciate the help and the link, it made things much clearer!